# igfxsrvc accessing the internet?

Tags: intel-graphics, internet-security

Why is igfxsrvc.exe (Intel Common User Interface) suddenly trying to access the internet?
Is it trying to update and why is it not using the Windows Update service to do so or something else is going on?

[image]